# File Management advice needed (Adobe Lightroom Classic)

Tags: file, aperture, adobe-lightroom

I'm finally getting around to moving my old Aperture library (~150,000 images) into Lightroom Classic and need a bit of advice regarding file management.

Here is my scenario:

- All of my images (from my current LR catalog and my Aperture library) were in a PHOTO_MASTERS folder, which is organzied by Year/Month (2021/01, 2021/02, etc)
- Over 15 years or so, there are other "extra" files in the PHOTOS_MASTERS folder that are NOT part of my current LR Catalog, nor part of my Aperture Library.
- I consolidated all the masters from my Aperture Library into Aperture, so they are no longer in the PHOTO_MASTERS folder
- Now in my PHOTO_MASTERS folder I have all the images from my LR Catalog, AND the extra images that are not in my LR Catalog.
- I want to separate these two groups of files so that I can review the extra images and decided what to do with them.

How can I separate the files that are part of my LR catalog from the remaining "extra" files?
I've reviewed all the options available in LR, but seems they are only useful for finding missing files, not extras.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (if I have understood the problem correctly):

I am going to find the Extra photos and (optionally) import them into a new folder in LR.

- In LR Classic, do an Import and choose your PHOTO_MASTERS folder.
- At the top click `New Photos`.

That will show you all the photos which are NOT in LR.

It might take a while if you already have lots of photos in the folder (or its sub-folders).

You can, if your want, import those files into the new LR folder:

- Choose `Move` at the top.
- On the right, as a Destination, create a new LR folder.
- Any other processing you want. That might include `Into Subfolder` by date.
- and `Import` (at the bottom-right).

Now you have identified the 'Extras' and separated them from the other photos whilst loading them into LR.